# How to get Applications of IIS AppPools into array?

Tags: windows, powershell, iis

To see all pools, their status and their applications inside `IIS:\AppPools\`, I use following command in PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools\
```

The output of this command is sorted in 3 columns named "*Name*", "*State*" and "*Applications*"; It will look like this example:

```
Name                     State        Applications
----                     -----        ------------
DefaultAppPool           Started      item
AnotherAppPool           Started      /item/item
AnotherAppPool2          Started      /item
AppPool XYZ              Started      item 1
                                      item 2
                                      item 3
...
```

My attempts at this point is to store the output of the command above into a array for later processing; Therefore I wrote following code in PowerShell:
(I annotated every step for better understanding)

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

# This array contains a hash table with the output of
# the command "Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools\":
$MY_IIS_APPLICATION_POOL = @{};

# "$COUNT" contains index number for each hash table in
# "$MY_IIS_APPLICATION_POOL"; It'll increased during
# the foreach-loop at its end:
$COUNT = 0;

# Looping each record/line of the command, to get the
# needed informations out of the several columns:
foreach ($RECORD in (Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools\)) {
  # Getting the needed records of each line:
  $POOL_NAME   = $RECORD.Name;
  $POOL_STATUS = $RECORD.State;
  $POOL_APPS   = "";

  # If there are more items in column "Applications":
  if ($RECORD.Applications -is [array]) {
    foreach ($APP in $RECORD.Applications) {
      $POOL_APPS = ($APP.ToString() + "," + $POOL_APPS);
    }
  } elseif ($RECORD.Applications -eq $NULL) {
    # Otherwise, if value is empty:
    $POOL_APPS = "---";
  } else {
    # Or if column contains only one value:
    $POOL_APPS = $RECORD.Applications.ToString();
  }

  # Defining Hash-Table in $MY_IIS_APPLICATION_POOL:
  $MY_IIS_APPLICATION_POOL[$COUNT] = @{
    'Name'   = $POOL_NAME;
    'Status' = $POOL_STATUS;
    'Apps'   = $POOL_APPS;
  };

  # Increase array index number for next hash table:
  $COUNT++;
}
```

This works well - I'm able to get the values by this scheme `$MY_ARRAY[0...9].Name` or for the status via `$MY_ARRAY[0...9].Status`. But I'm getting empty values by fetching the "Applications" column: `$MY_ARRAY[0...9].Apps` is always empty.

So does anybody know how to get the values form the column "Applications"?

Comment: Were you meaning to access your array by `$MY_ARRAY[0...9].Apps` instead of `$MY_ARRAY[0...9].App`?

Comment: @HeedfulCrayon: No, that's not what I asked for.  ``$MY_ARRAY[0...9].App`` was just a typo. Did you execute ``Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools\`` and tried to get the values out of the column _"Applications"_?

Comment: What exactly are you planning on doing with this array once you have it?  The reason why I ask is that it may be better to just save all applications to a variable like so `$iisApps = Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\AppPools` and then you can use other WebAdministration commandlets to accomplish the rest like `Get-WebApplication` or `Get-Website`, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The reason `Applications` is always empty is because this is not actually a property on the object being returned. This data is being created in the console output by an [output formatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-6) in the webadministration module.

You can take a look at the properties available if you pipe your app pool object to `Get-Member`. You'll notice that `Applications` doesn't exist as a member. If you grab the full type name from `Get-Member`

```
Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement#system.applicationHost/applicationPools#add
```

you can head on over to the webadministration module to take a closer look. Typically you'll find this at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\WebAdministration`

Inside the module you'll find a file called `iisprovider.format.ps1xml` that is handling the output formatting. If you pop that open and search for the type name you'll find the code that's running to produce the output you see in the `Applications` column. The table column isn't named so you'll just have to count to the third column to find it. It looks like this.

```
<TableColumnItem>
   <ScriptBlock>
     $pn = $_.Name
     $sites = get-webconfigurationproperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool=`'$pn`'and @path='/']/parent::*" machine/webroot/apphost -name name
     $apps = get-webconfigurationproperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool=`'$pn`'and @path!='/']" machine/webroot/apphost -name path
     $arr = @()
     if ($sites -ne $null) {$arr += $sites}
     if ($apps -ne $null) {$arr += $apps}
     if ($arr.Length -gt 0) {
        $out = ""
        foreach ($s in $arr) {$out += $s.Value + "`n"}
        $out.Substring(0, $out.Length - 1)
     }
   </ScriptBlock>
</TableColumnItem>
```

You could pipe the output from `Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools\` to `Out-String` like `$appPoolText = Get-ChildItem –Path IIS:\AppPools\ | Out-String` and then parse it but that seems like a lot of work. For my use I just converted the formatter code into a function I could use.

```
function GetAppsInPool($pn) {
    $sites = get-webconfigurationproperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool=`'$pn`'and @path='/']/parent::*" machine/webroot/apphost -name name
    $apps = get-webconfigurationproperty "/system.applicationHost/sites/site/application[@applicationPool=`'$pn`'and @path!='/']" machine/webroot/apphost -name path
    $arr = @()
    if ($sites -ne $null) {$arr += $sites}
    if ($apps -ne $null) {$arr += $apps}
    if ($arr.Length -gt 0) {
        $out = ""
        foreach ($s in $arr) {$out += $s.Value + "`n"}
        $out.Substring(0, $out.Length - 1)
    }
}
```

You could then technically use that with `Select-Object` to create an inline custom object with a calculated property that would look the way you want it to. Something like

`Get-ChildItem IIS:\AppPools\ | select Name,State,@{n='Applications';e={GetAppsInPool -pn $_.Name}}`